# Can't understand this set theory proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-proofs

I read the proof of a 'set theory' equation from a website called Meritnation. But I can't understand the proof after 30 minutes of trying and even find some mistakes in it.

This is the proof(I have copied it from a particular website and numbered the lines)

[image]

Now in line 5, it says $x \in (A \cap B)$ which is a subset to $(A \cup B) \cup (A-B).$ I think the $(A-B)$ is not required as $A \cup B$ already contains $(A-B).$ Same goes for line 10.

I can't understand the purpose of line 8 to 10 and line 11 comes out all of a sudden. From line 11, everything is easily understood and seems correct but almost all of the lines before it seem either wrong or unnecessary. Please help.

Comment: To be honest it seems like a rather ugly proof (and it's not even a formal proof, in the math. logic sense).  Hidden in multitude of lines, the essential facts are $A\cap B\subset A$ and $A\setminus B\subset A$, so $(A\cap B)\cup (A\setminus B)\subset A$, and given $x\in A$, either $x\in B$ (so $x\in A\cap B$) or $x\notin B$ (so $x\in A\setminus B$), and hence $x\in (A\cap B)\cup (A\setminus B)$.

Comment: I think there is a typo in Line 5. It's $A \cap B,$ not $A \cup B.$ (Though $A\cup B$ is not wrong, but you don't need it here.) Line 8-10 is wrongly written: $x \notin A \cap B \Rightarrow x \in A$ and $x \notin B.$ (You have started with $x \in A.$) So $x \in A - B.$ (And I agree with @Hayden. It's a very ugly written proof, full of mistakes.)

Comment: To start with: Lines 1-16 prove one statement (on line 0). Lines 17-31 are to prove a second statement (on line 17).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines 7-8: If $x$ is not in $A\cap B$, there are two overlapping subcases: $x\not\in A$ and/or $x\not\in B$.

Line 9: But the first subcase contradicts line 1, therefore certainly $x\not\in B$.

Line 10 should say that $x\in A,\ x\not\in B\implies x\in A-B$ which is $\subset (A\cap B)\cup(A-B)$.

Comment: And there's an error in line 5, as Krish pointed out in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer to your question, but here is an alternative proof, in a calculational style, which is a lot shorter and should be a lot simpler to follow.

So I'm posting this in the hope that it is helpful.

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\followsfrom}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
$Let's simplify $\;(A \cap B) \cup (A - B)\;$, by calculating which elements $\;x\;$ it contains: for all $\;x\;$,

$$\calc
x \in (A \cap B) \cup (A - B)
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\cup\;$}
x \in A \cap B \;\lor\; x \in A - B
\op\equiv\hint{definition of $\;\cap\;$; definition of $\;-\;$}
(x \in A \land x \in B) \;\lor\; (x \in A \land x \not\in B)
\op\equiv\hint{logic: extract common conjunct, i.e., $\;\land\;$ distributes over $\;\lor\;$}
x \in A \;\land\; (x \in B \lor x \not\in B)
\op\equiv\hint{logic: excluded middle}
x \in A \;\land\; \true
\op\equiv\hint{logic: simplify}
x \in A
\endcalc$$

Therefore, by set extensionality, $\;(A \cap B) \cup (A - B) \;=\; A\;$.

Comment: Beautiful! (I wonder if the excluded middle is necessary, though… Probably.)